# What is the best variable type for a soccer result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables, types

I'd like to build a program which predicts soccer results. Now I was wondering, what the best way was to store the soccer result in a variable.
I thought of a few different options but there are probably others:

1. In a string e.g. "2:1"
2. In an array e.g. [2, 1]
3. In an object e.g. {homeTeam: 2, awayTeam: 1}

I will not have to iterate over the result, I just have to read the value in an easy way.

I'm currently using javascript. I've heard that there are new types of arrays in ES6 like Maps and Sets but I haven't read into them. Is it better to use these array types?
Which do you think is the best or are there any other better ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an array, the order is guaranteed, but you need to know which order it's in - `[away, home]` or `[home, away]`. For this reason it's easier to use an object, and you can also determine wins and losses fairly simply as well - and you can send data to other areas with JSON:

```js
const result = { home: 2, away: 1 };
console.log(`The home team scores ${result.home}`);
console.log(`The away team scored ${result.away}`);
const winner = result.home > result.away ? "Home" : (result.away > result.home ? "Away" : "Draw");
console.log(winner == "Draw" ? `It was a draw!` : `The winner is the ${winner} team`);
```

Comment: 2 comments: 1. Since normally, the result is said in "home":"away" order anyways, I think an array is not a problem.
2. What do you know about using a set/map? Are these viable options?

Comment: The issue is not in what order we speak the scores. The issue is in making it easier for the developer to understand the code. Switching between an Array and an Object is almost no difference in memory size, but a huge difference in readability.

Comment: @IceRevenge But what if someone who receives the data doesn't know which order the array is in? A Set is similar to an array, but a Map would also work, as it's a key-value based system.

Comment: @Intervalia okay that makes sense. I'm not working with other developers, just doing this for fun, but it's probably a good practice to use an object in those situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide more context of what you're trying to achieve would be great.
As you mentioned you are not going to iterate over the result, then how you are going to get the values when the length of the string or array increases? If there are always two values only  `"2:1", [2,1], {homeTeam: 2, awayTeam: 1}` then it's your personal preference how you like to get the values, the time complexity always will be O(1). For example, you can get values from a string `const strToArr = "2:1".split(':'); strToArr[0]` and `strToArr[1]`, from array `const arr = [2,1]; arr[0]` and `arr[1]` or from object `cont obj = {homeTeam: 2, awayTeam: 1}; obj.homeTeam` and `obj.awayTeam` ... And of course you also can use Map : `const map = new Map(); map.set('homeTeam', 2); map.set('awayTeam', 1); map.get('homeTeam'); map.get('awayTeam');` For Set keep in mind that it stores unique values and might not be a good choice unless you handle it properly